# Powershell replace 26th character in a string with a sequence number

Tags: powershell, replace, character, substring

1. I want to replace the 26th character of the string that is starting with “M” and I want to put a sequence number starting from zero and Sequence# + 1 in any later string.
2. File contains these strings:

```
M453023455697RR23047230426485111814XXXXXX                                    

RAPPAREL/ACCESSORIES               

SHOES

L03984798239409970924MM09709745340979XXXXXX

M98802734207KK972839482326485111814XXXXXX
```

3. My Powershell script:

```powershell
$SequenceStart = 1
$String = "M"
$str2 = "$xfiles.substring(0,24)"
$str3 = "$xfiles.substring(25)"
$str4 = "$xfiles.substring(26,53)"
$str5 = "$xfiles.substring(0,80)"
$Line = "$str2""$str+1""$str4"


$xfiles = Get-ChildItem $InFiles
Write-Host "Found " ($xfiles | Measure-Object).count " files to process"


If (($xfiles | Measure-Object).count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($xfile in $xfiles)
    {
        Write-Host "Processing file: $xFile`r"

        $cnt = $SequenceStart

        $content = Get-Content -path $xfile

        $content | foreach {
            If ($_.Contains($String)) {
                $_ -replace $String, $Line}
            else {$_}
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Your code is also incomplete since we dont see where `$InFiles` is declared ... not that it really impacts the question but there might be other stuff missing like the closing brace on the `if` statement and `foreach`. What is wrong exactly since you didnt say?

Comment: Yes, this script is not working and I want to know how to achieve this. I also forgot to declare a variable $ str = $ str3. But even after this It is not working. Thanks

Comment: $InFiles = path to CDMS.txt which is the file that contains data. I want to know how I can write an IF statement or if this script can be adjusted instead. Any hint would be appreciated.  Thx

Comment: The sequence number... does that represent every match of an M line? so the 5th M line in a file would have a sequence number of 5? Does it replace the 26th character or push it down. What are you doing with the data once you are done? Writing it back to the same file?

Comment: The fifth line would have number 1. So where a line is starting with M, I want to replace the 26th character with 0 and add 1 to it everytime 26th character is replaced. So I would have a sequence in the M series of lines. Thx

Comment: First line startin with M: 26th character = 0 , second line startin with M: 26th character = 1 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And one other option just for yucks:

```
foreach ($xFile in $xFiles) {
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing file: $xFile"
    $counter = 0
    Get-Content $xFile | Foreach {
        [regex]::replace($_, '(^M.{24}).(.*)', 
            {param($m) $m.Groups[1].Value + ($global:counter++) + $m.Groups[2].Value})
    } | Out-File $xFile.FullName
}
```

Gotta love good ol' MatchEvaluator but unfortunately, due to the way PowerShell handles the callback this approach is slow.

Comment: Thanks guys. All solutions worked but I used the one that Keith suggested. Thanks Keith.

Answer (score 1):

Bored at work... Ok, easiest way I know of to do this is this:

Read the file with Get-Content, loop through all lines, and if it starts with an M do the replace and increment the counter.

```
foreach ($xfile in $xfiles)
{
    Write-Host "Processing file: $xFile`r"
    $counter = 0
    (Get-Content $xfile | ForEach{
        If($_ -match "^m"){$_ -replace "(?<=^.{25})(.)",$counter;$counter++}else{$_}
    })|out-file $xfile.fullname
}
```

Comment: Good work. Havent seen you in a while. Regex was going to be the search. Didnt occur to me to use it for replace as well.

Comment: Got a new gig as a vendor at MS so I've been busy learning the ropes. Should be back more regularly again though =)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
foreach ($xfile in $xfiles)
{
    Write-Host "Processing file: $xFile`r"
    $counter = 0
    (Get-Content $xfile | ForEach{
      if ($_ -match '^(M.{24}).(.+)')
        {'{0}{1}{2}' -f $matches[1],$counter++,$matches[2]}
      else {$_}  
    })|out-file $xfile.fullname
}
```

Comment: Um, you do `$Counter = 0` and then `$i++`. I never remember that I can increment and use the variable at the same time. I suppose I could shorten my `$counter;$counter++` to be just `$counter++`.

Comment: Missed that. Thanks for the catch.  It's a little more work to code, but maybe more intuitive depending on your comfort level with regex.